# How to move label of input text field above when user clicks on input field - angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a input type="text" field. By intially the field should contain field name. When user clicks on that input field the field name should move up and leave space to enter the value.

I searched in google but I couldn't found any solution related to my need.

It will be great if anyone could help me.

[Initally form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XgG1.png)

[After clicking on field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPujj.png)

Comment: You're looking for material input box.

Comment: in angular material this is available https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want can be achieved by implementing material design. Use this: https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH

```css
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

/* basic stylings ------------------------------------------ */
body      { background:url(http://scotch.io/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/61.jpg); }
.container   { 
  font-family:'Roboto';
  width:600px; 
  margin:30px auto 0; 
  display:block; 
  background:#FFF;
  padding:10px 50px 50px;
}
h2    { 
  text-align:center; 
  margin-bottom:50px; 
}
h2 small { 
  font-weight:normal; 
  color:#888; 
  display:block; 
}
.footer  { text-align:center; }
.footer a  { color:#53B2C8; }

/* form starting stylings ------------------------------- */
.group      { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}
input     {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
input:focus   { outline:none; }

/* LABEL ======================================= */
label      {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}

/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar  { position:relative; display:block; width:300px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#5264AE; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <h2>Google Material Design in CSS3<small>Inputs</small></h2>
  
  <form>
    
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
      
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    
  </form>
      
  <p class="footer">
    a <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/css/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3" target="_blank">tutorial</a> by <a href="http://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a>
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use material design and you can use `md-input-container`

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text">
</md-input-container>
```

[Material design input](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input)